# Remote Desktop Service behavior issue, RemoteApp kept freezing

Tags: rds

My issue is while launching the RemoteApp it keeps spinning and says "Configuring remote session". Not all the time, though. It was launching a while ago and signed off. Now again launched the RemoteApp it just spinning.

[image]
And when I try to cancel it won't Cancel the RemoteApp I have to kill through the Task manager.

After killing it, I launched again and it just worked as expected

I need to get this fixed. Please suggest a resolution for me.

RDS is on Windows server 2012 R2
Client launching from Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Could you please let us know the following details.

1. Is this a recurring issue or 1 time occurred issue?
2. Please try to telnet the remote machine and check whether it's reachable or not when this problem occurs and share the feedback with us.

And also try the below solutions also, may be it'll fix this RDB freezing issue.

Try to see whether reducing Graphics helps. 
This seems to have helped in few cases. This verifies whether you have the correct graphics driver.

Here’s how:

1. Right click the Windows desktop and choose Personalize.
2. Click "Display Settings".
3. Click "Advanced Settings”.
4. Click on "Troubleshoot" tab.
5. Click on "Change Settings".
6. On the resulting Display Adapter Troubleshooter dialog box, drag the slider one notch to the left.

If changing the video hardware acceleration solves the problem, it's a signal that your computer's video driver isn't quite perfect.

In such cases, download the driver from the link below.

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid=&SystemID=STUDIOXPS8100

Connect and see if there’s any improvement.

Security software could also be one of the reasons.

Temporarily disable them and verify the result.

Try disabling Receive Window Auto-Tuning.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Go to Start and type cmd.
2. Right-click on cmd and select “Run as administrator”.
3. Type: netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled and press Enter.

If you want to to re-enable it:

Type: netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal and press Enter.

If this doesn’t help, please post your concerns at Technet forums for further support.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/threads

Note: Ensure to enable all your security software by now.

If the above steps unsuccess, use below steps and try the same.

1. Logon to the Remote Desktop Services Session Host computer as an administrator
2. Start--Run gpedit.msc
3. In the left pane, under Computer Configuration, navigate to following:
   Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment
4. In the right pane, double-click on Set compression algorithm for RDP data
5. Select Enabled, and choose Balances memory and network bandwidth
6. Click OK to save the change

Comment: this issues happening sometimes only. I already created a request in Technet forum, here is the link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/122cb555-a1d5-4d02-81bd-da8ef5176dd1/remoteapp-connection-freezing?forum=winserverTS .

Comment: Noted, were you able to do the suggested workarounds?

Comment: I applied those workarounds. However, I can't really tell if this is fixed or not because the issue happening sometimes only.

Comment: I think this has resolved the issue. So far I didn't notice the freezing issue again. However, I see the RemoteApp taking too long than usual.  Could you explain me what does the "netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled" command does

Comment: I'm still seeing the RemoteApp is freezing

Comment: Did you restart the pc after applying those mentioned fixes?

Comment: Group policy I applied through Active Directory to all 20 Session host servers. Do I need to restart them.  I ran the ": netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled" command on my windows 10 workstation. Do I need to restart my workstation? Here is the thing I cannot ask the client to run the command on their workstation since they'll ask more questions about why they need to run like that.

Comment: It's better if you could restart(with the client permission) them to apply the necessary changes properly.